# Getting rid of empty space in tkinter embedded matplotlib graph

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm embedding certain graphs into my tkinter GUI, and I noticed I have a lot of "empty space" around the figure.

[image: Empty Space]

There are 3 frames in the picture, first containing buttons above the figure, second containing the canvas that contains the figure, and third containing the test.

I've checked the graphs by plotting them outside of TkAgg and there is minimum empty space, so I suspect something goes wrong when I call FigureCanvasTkAgg.

Is it possible to control how much a matplotlib Figure fills Canvas widget?

code below:

```
canvas=FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure,master=canvasframe)
widget=canvas.get_tk_widget()
widget.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the error. Error was in adding subplots to figure, I added with:

```
.add_subplots(221)
```

instead of

```
.add_subplots(121)
```

Really really basic error.